# Node.js API with Express an async: Trouble with multiple request

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous

I am new to node.js and trying to create a small API. I am using Express for routing and async.jc for processing the Calls Step by Step. This works fine when only one Request comes in, but when i try to fire 2 or more requests from my Machine the process is mixing up values in variables and crashes.

Here is short snippet from my source:

```
router.get('/new', function (request, res) {
    async.waterfall([
        function(callback) {

            // get a unique domain
            client.spop('domainSet', function(err, domain) {
                userdata = {
                    email: 'user' + '@' + domain + '.' + mydomain,
                    password: randomstring.generate(10),
                    username: domain,
                    name: domain,
                    confirm: "false"
                }
                if (err) return next(err);
                callback(null, userdata, userdata.password);
            })

        },
        function(userdata, userpwd, callback) {
            myapp.users.create(userdata, function(user) {
                console.log('Creating new user: ' + userdata.email);
                callback(null, user, userpwd);
            });
        },
```

How is it possible to keep the "context/scope" per request? i am sure im missing something (-: Or is the only problem that i fire the request from the same Machine??

Comment: `userdata` in the first function is not declared anywhere, so it is getting global scope. try `var userdata = {`

Comment: ahhh ;) Thanks - if you create a answer from your comment i will accept it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`userdata` in the first waterfall function needs to be declared within that function, otherwise it has global scope.

```
router.get('/new', function (request, res) {
    async.waterfall([
        function(callback) {

            // get a unique domain
            client.spop('domainSet', function(err, domain) {
                var userdata = {
                    email: 'user' + '@' + domain + '.' + mydomain,
                    password: randomstring.generate(10),
                    username: domain,
                    name: domain,
                    confirm: "false"
                }
                if (err) return next(err);
                callback(null, userdata, userdata.password);
            })

        },
        function(userdata, userpwd, callback) {
            myapp.users.create(userdata, function(user) {
                console.log('Creating new user: ' + userdata.email);
                callback(null, user, userpwd);
            });
        },
```